Efficient sky searches with HEALPix-alchemy
I am trying to implement a cone search for a catalog with the HEALPix-alchemy package. I have the following models set up, based on the examples here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.06947
class Field(Base):
    """
    Represents a collection of FieldTiles making up the area of interest.
    """
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    tiles = relationship(lambda: FieldTile, order_by="FieldTile.id")


class FieldTile(Base):
    """
    A HEALPix tile that is a component of the Field being selected.
    """
    id = Column(ForeignKey(Field.id), primary_key=True)
    hpx = Column(Tile, index=True)
    pk = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


class Source(Base):
    """
    Represents a source and its location.
    """

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    Heal_Pix_Position = Column(Point, index=True, nullable=False)

I am then using CDSHealpix to get the HEALPix cells contained within a specified cone.
I construct the Multi Order Coverage map from the HEALPix cells using MOCpy and extract the HEALPix tiles using HEALPix-alchemy.
I then populate the Field table with this collection of tiles.
Finally, I perform the following query:
query = db.query(Source).filter(FieldTile.hpx.contains(Source.Heal_Pix_Position)).all()

However, this is very inefficient as I am effectively checking each source in my catalog to see if it is contained within a FieldTile.
How can I modify my approach so that I am checking each tile and returning the sources that it contains?

please provide a simplified example that can be executed without access to your database. A technique generally useful for problems like this is using the hierarchy of healpix pixels. If you use the "nested" indexing, you can easily downgrade a pixel number to a lower resolution by doing np.floor(pix/8). So you can do searches at a lower resolution which are way quicker.

Does the contains_lonlat method in mocpy help? It returns True if a source is in a MOC and False otherwise. You can feed it columns/lists of coordinates. See the example in mocpy's documentation https://cds-astro.github.io/mocpy/stubs/mocpy.MOC.html#mocpy.MOC.contains_lonlat
PS: you can do a MOC from a cone directly too. With MOC.from_cone. Would allow you to skip the cds-healpix-python step.
